# Dynamic indirect Bash array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have logs in this format:

```
log1,john,time,etc
log2,peter,time,etc
log3,jack,time,etc
log4,peter,time,etc
```

I want to create a list for every person in the format

```
"name"=("no.lines" "line" "line" ...)
```

For example:

```
peter=("2" "log2,peter,time,etc" "log4,peter,time,etc")
```

I already have this structure and know how to create variables like

```
declare "${FIELD[1]}"=1
```

but I don't know how to increase number of records and I am getting an error if I want to create a list like this and append into it.

```
#!/bin/bash

F=("log1,john,time,etc" "log2,peter,time,etc" "log3,jack,time,etc" "log4,peter,time,etc")
echo "${F[@]}"

declare -a CLIENTS
for LINE in "${F[@]}"
do
    echo "$LINE"
    IFS=',' read -ra  FIELD < <(echo "$LINE")

    if [ -z "${!FIELD[1]}" ] && [ -n "${FIELD[1]}" ] # check if there is already record for given line, if not create
    then 
            CLIENTS=("${CLIENTS[@]}" "${FIELD[1]}") # add person to list of variables records for later access
            declare -a "${FIELD[1]}"=("1" "LINE") # ERROR

    elif [ -n "${!FIELD[1]}" ] && [ -n "${FIELD[1]}" ] # if already record for client
    then 
            echo "Increase records number" # ???
            echo "Append record"
            "${FIELD[@]}"=("${FIELD[@]}" "$LINE") # ERROR

    else    
            echo "ELSE"
    fi

done

echo -e "CLIENTS: \n ${CLIENTS[@]}"
echo "Client ${CLIENTS[0]} has ${!CLIENTS[0]} records"
echo "Client ${CLIENTS[1]} has ${!CLIENTS[1]} records"
echo "Client ${CLIENTS[2]} has ${!CLIENTS[2]} records"
echo "Client ${CLIENTS[3]} has ${!CLIENTS[3]} records"
```

Comment: Which version of bash? 4.3 has a new data structure borrowed from ksh made just for the purpose.

Comment: ...btw, if you'll pardon a bit of kibitzing: All-caps variable names are reserved by convention for variables that impact (or indicate) shell or system state; your own variables should use names with at least one lower-case character. See fourth paragraph of relevant spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Also, there's **absolutely no need** to have the number of lines be an array element itself -- you can just get that by asking an array containing only the data at hand for its length.

Comment: Don't code text processing in bash, it is simply the wrong tool for the job. This is why the answers are not in bash.

Comment: @msw, eh? I have a perfectly good answer written in native bash. :)

Comment: That's a use of "perfectly good" that I've not seen before. o.O

Comment: @msw, detailed criticism and critique is welcome.

Comment: Thank's a lot to **all of you guys** for all insights! I am quite new in Bash scripting and this is roughly my 3rd script. So next time I'll try to use Awk or Sed for this kind of task. Btw could you recommend some good book about Bash scripting? And If i understand it well, I should use tools like grep, sed, awk, coreutils etc. and just "glue" it together right?

Comment: @MichalGonda, actually, **no** -- using external tools is bad form if you want your scripts to be fast when processing small amounts of data! If you want a good place to start that has a heavy focus on best practices, the BashGuide at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is excellent.

Comment: @MichalGonda, ...grep, awk, sed, &c. will be much faster than bash builtins when you're working with thousands of lines of input, but the startup time for any tool not built into the shell itself is nontrivial, and such tools should never be invoked *inside* an inner loop (when you're starting a new instance of one of them for each line of input processed). bash is, itself, an inherently slow shell -- but if you do it right, your code will be much faster if run by a higher-performing shell (such as ksh93); do it wrong, and it'll always be slow by virtue of constantly starting external tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I get the point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bash with Coreutils, grep and sed

If I understand your code right, you try to have multidimensional arrays, which Bash doesn't support. If I were to solve this problem from scratch, I'd use this mix of command line tools (see security concerns at the end of the answer!):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name; do
    printf "%s=(\"%d\" \"%s\")\n" \
        "$name" \
        "$(grep -c "$name" "$1")" \
        "$(grep "$name" "$1" | tr $'\n' ' ' | sed 's/ /" "/g;s/" "$//')"
done < <(cut -d ',' -f 2 "$1" | sort -u)
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./SO.sh infile
jack=("1" "log3,jack,time,etc")
john=("1" "log1,john,time,etc")
peter=("2" "log2,peter,time,etc" "log4,peter,time,etc")
```

This uses process substitution to prepare the log file so we can loop over unique names; the output of the substitution looks like

```
$ cut -d ',' -f 2 "$1" | sort -u
jack
john
peter
```

i.e., a list of unique names.

For each name, we then print the summarized log line with

```
printf "%s=(\"%d\" \"%s\")\n"
```

Where

- The `%s` string is just the name (`"$name"`).
- The log line count is the output of a grep command,

  ```
  grep -c "$name" "$1"
  ```

  which counts the number of occurrences of `"$name"`. If the name can occur elsewhere in the log line, we can limit the search to just the second field of the log lines with

  ```
  grep -c "$name" <(cut -d ',' -f 2 "$1")
  ```
- Finally, to get all log lines on one line with proper quoting and all, we use

  ```
  grep "$name" "$1" | tr $'\n' ' ' | sed 's/ /" "/g;s/" "$//'
  ```

  This gets all lines containing `"$name"`, replaces newlines with spaces, then surrounds the spaces with quotes and removes the extra quotes from the end of the line.

#### Pure Bash

After initially thinking that pure Bash would be too cumbersome, it turned out to be not all that complicated:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A count
declare -A lines

old_ifs=IFS
IFS=,
while read -r -a line; do
    name="${line[1]}"
    (( ++count[$name] ))
    lines[$name]+="\"${line[*]}\" "
done < "$1"

for name in "${!count[@]}"; do
    printf "%s=(\"%d\" %s)\n" "$name" "${count[$name]}" "${lines[$name]% }"
done

IFS="$old_ifs"
```

This updates two associative arrays while looping over the input file: `count` keeps track of the number of times a certain name occurs, and `lines` appends the log lines to an entry per name.

To separate fields by commas, we set the input field separator `IFS` to a comma (but save it beforehand so it can be reset at the end).

`read -r -a` reads the lines into an array `line` with comma separated fields, so the name is now in `${line[1]}`. We increase the count for that name in the arithmetic expression `(( ... ))`, and append (`+=`) the log line in the next line.

`${line[*]}` prints all fields of the array separated by `IFS`, which is exactly what we want. We also add a space here; the unwanted space at the end of the line (after the last element) will be removed later.

The second loop iterates over all the keys of the `count` array (the names), then prints the properly formatted line for each. `${lines[$name]% }` removes the space from the end of the line.

**Security concerns**

As it seems that the output of these scripts is supposed to be reused by the shell, we might want to prevent malicious code execution if we can't trust the contents of the log file.

A way to do that for the Bash solution (hat tip: [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)) would be the following: the for loop would have to be replaced by

```
for name in "${!count[@]}"; do
    IFS=' ' read -r -a words <<< "${lines[$name]}"
    printf -v words_str '%q ' "${words[@]}"
    printf "%q=(\"%d\" %s)\n" "$name" "${count[$name]}" "${words_str% }"
done
```

That is, we split the combined log lines into an array `words`, print that with the `%q` formatting flag into a string `words_str` and then use that string for our output, resulting in escaped output like this:

```
peter=("2" \"log2\,peter\,time\,etc\" \"log4\,peter\,time\,etc\")
jack=("1" \"log3\,jack\,time\,etc\")
john=("1" \"log1\,john\,time\,etc\")
```

The analogous could be done for the first solution.

Comment: Assuming that the OP wants to *execute* the generated code, using `%s` rather than `%q` in your printf format strings is wildly unsafe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you expand on that?

Comment: This does not produce the correct output for peter. `peter=("1" "log2,peter,time,etc")`

Comment: @BenjaminW., think about what happens if the input contains `$(rm -rf .)` in the CSV file, and the user tries to evaluate the output (as the specified output form is clearly intended to be eval-able).

Comment: @dawg It does here...? `peter=("2" "log2,peter,time,etc" "log4,peter,time,etc")` Requires that the input file ends with a newline, though. As it should be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got it!

Comment: Hmm. The updated behavior isn't quite right either -- printf %q is going to be escaping the whitespace *between* array elements -- but that's hard to avoid without either breaking CSV rows with literal whitespace in the data or fixing the data model to no longer store each user's data as a long string rather than an array.

Comment: ...I suppose if you'd rather break the whitespace case than break your security, that would be something like: `IFS=' ' read -r -a words <<<"${lines[$name]}"; printf -v words_str '%q ' "${words[@]}"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've updated the answer to address this separately at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Be warned: The below uses namevars, a new bash 4.3 feature.

---

First: I would strongly suggest namespacing your arrays with a prefix to avoid collisions with unrelated variables. Thus, using `content_` as that prefix:

```
read_arrays() {
  while IFS= read -r line && IFS=, read -r -a fields <<<"$line"; do
    name=${fields[1]}
    declare -g -a "content_${fields[1]}"
    declare -n cur_array="content_${fields[1]}"
    cur_array+=( "$line" )
    unset -n cur_array
  done
}
```

Then:

```
lines_for() {
  declare -n cur_array="content_$1"
  printf '%s\n' "${#cur_array[@]}" ## emit length of array for given person
}
```

...or...

```
for_each_line() {
  declare -n cur_array="content_$1"; shift
  for line in "${cur_array[@]}"; do
    "$@" "$line"
  done
}
```

Tying all this together:

```
$ read_arrays <<'EOF'
log1,john,time,etc
log2,peter,time,etc
log3,jack,time,etc
log4,peter,time,etc
EOF
$ lines_for peter
2
$ for_each_line peter echo
log2,peter,time,etc
log4,peter,time,etc
```

---

...and, if you **really** want the format you asked for, with the number of columns as explicit data, and variable names that aren't safely namespaced, it's easy to convert from one to the other:

```
# this should probably be run in a subshell to avoid namespace pollution
# thus, (generate_stupid_format) >output
generate_stupid_format() {
  for scoped_varname in "${!content_@}"; do
    unscoped_varname="${scoped_varname#content_}"
    declare -n unscoped_var=$unscoped_varname
    declare -n scoped_var=$scoped_varname
    unscoped_var=( "${#scoped_var[@]}" "${scoped_var[@]}" )
    declare -p "$unscoped_varname"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`. As a demo:

```
awk -F, '{a1[$2]=a1[$2]" \""$0"\""; sum[$2]++} END{for (e in sum){print e"=("  "\""sum[e]"\""a1[e]")"}}' file
john=("1" "log1,john,time,etc")
peter=("2" "log2,peter,time,etc" "log4,peter,time,etc")
jack=("1" "log3,jack,time,etc")
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Be aware, though, that `awk` doesn't know how to escape content to make it `eval`-safe by a shell; if your input file contained `...,etc,$(rm -rf ~)`, you'd have a bad day when trying to load it into your shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed. I left the implications to the user I suppose and simply answered the query...